# Tipo Hora Genexus

Tags: genexus

Tenho uma variável na minha aplicação do tipo `Varchar` em que recebo somente horas nele. Porem, queria formatar a mascara `":"` nele, depois da hora e antes do minuto, ao colocar na propriedade Picture o valor: 99:99, ao abrir a tela aparece os ":", porem ao digitar qualquer valor no campo a formatação não fica.

Ex: se eu digitar 0842, era pra formatar sozinho 08:42 porém não está formatando.
Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pictures em GeneXus tem um comportamento particular. Especificamente para os atributos e variáveis de tipo Character (Varchar, etc) somente se consideram aquelas [predefinidas](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6800,Pictures).

Pode definir uma variável de tipo TIME, e nesse caso sim terá em conta a picture 99:99.